# Spring Security conditional default-target-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've noticed that there are a couple of questions asking about this topic. I looked through them and I was unable to apply them to my specific Spring setup. I would like to configure my login redirect to be conditional, based on the user's role. This is what I have so far:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <custom-filter ref="filterSecurityInterceptor" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/index?error=true"
            />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index" invalidate-session="true"/>
</http>
```

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139718/spring-security-changing-spring-security-login-form) might be in the same line as what I'm trying to do. Anyone know how I can apply it though?

**EDIT 1**

```
<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**EDIT 2**

Currently I do not have a class like `public class Test implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {}` as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470405/authenticationsuccesshandler-example-for-spring-security-3/7470476#7470476).

Comment: Your question is identical to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470405/authenticationsuccesshandler-example-for-spring-security-3)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please check **EDIT 1**. I'm getting confused because I'm already assigning a spring class to that bean?

Comment: Hasn't form-login an authenticationSuccessHandler? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html

Comment: @ThreaT this was shown in the [Luke's link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7470476/241986)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have tested the code and it works, there's no rocket science in it

```
public class MySuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            response.sendRedirect("/Admin.html");   
            return;
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/User.html");
    }    
}
```

Changes in your security context:

```
<bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="my.domain.MySuccessHandler">
    </bean>

<security:form-login ... authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"/>
```

**update** if you want to use `default-target-url` approach, it will work equally well, but will be triggered when your user first accesses the login page:

`<security:form-login default-target-url="/welcome.htm" />`

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome.htm")
    protected View welcome() {

        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils
                .authorityListToSet(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return new RedirectView("Admin.htm");
        }
        return new RedirectView("User.htm");
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to redirect to anther domain? @Boris Treukhov

Comment: In case anyone is using Java code for Sprint context: `formLogin().successHandler(new MySuccessHandler())`

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate approach IMO is to create a class which extends `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and then override its `determineTargetUrl` method. From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html#determineTargetUrl(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)):

> Builds the target URL according to the logic defined in the main class Javadoc.

...which sounds a little confusing, but basically you write whatever logic you need to determine the target URL, then just return it as a String.