# secure two or more /** url in spring security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am having trouble in securing two URLs using Springs Security. I want to secure /admin/** and /user/**. The major issue is I have separate tables for ADMIN as ADMIN & ADMIN_ROLES and for USER as USER & USER_ROLES. I am also having separate login pages for Admin and User as well. I am sharing my code below. Please help me with this issue.

What I need is when some goes to /admin URL it should display Admin Login Page and redirect me to /admin/embassy, and when some open / URL it should to User Login Page and on successful login should redirect me to /user/embassy.

> spring-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/user/embassy"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED from USER where USERNAME = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.USERNAME, ur.AUTHORITY from USER u, USER_ROLES ur where u.ID = ur.USER_ID and u.USERNAME =?"
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/admin" default-target-url="/admin/embassy"
        authentication-failure-url="/adminloginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/adminlogout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED from ADMIN where USERNAME = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select a.USERNAME, ar.AUTHORITY from ADMIN a, ADMIN_ROLES ar where a.ID = ar.USER_ID and a.USERNAME =?"
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

> web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/User-servlet.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/Admin-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/Spring-Datasource.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Quite frankly I would use a unified table structure, it makes things *a lot* easier.

Comment: Okay even if I use a single table but what I need to redirect to /admin/embassy when the person is having Admin Role and /user/embassy when the person is having User Role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the comments I guess you have no problem with a single table
so I assume it.
So your `spring-security.xml` should look like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/" authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED from USER where USERNAME = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.USERNAME, ur.AUTHORITY from USER u, USER_ROLES ur where u.ID = ur.USER_ID and u.USERNAME =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Where I assume all your Users and Admins are now in User table.
And now impl. [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), and register it as a bean with the same name as the value of aboves `athentication-success-handler-ref`, that redirects to the page you want.

```
public class MySuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            response.sendRedirect("/admin/embassy");   
            return;
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/user/embassy");
    }    
}
```

So we add to the `spring-security.xml`

```
<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="my.domain.MySuccessHandler" />
```

Comment: He already has two http elements, one for admin and one for user.

Comment: @Ralph yes you are right did not see it but now I write a solution that should be detailed enough to understand the way it works and costumize it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked in an excellent way for me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get a very customized authentication scheme, you need to bypass a lot of  `http` namespace functionality for that to work. Some things you will need:

- Two [`AuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) instances, one for each login page
- A custom [`AuthenticationDetailsSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationDetailsSource.html) injected to your [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html), in order to store some context into the [`Authentication`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) instances that allows you to determine if the login page the user is logging in through is the ADMIN one or the USER one.
- A customized `AuthenticationManager` instance that retrieves that context using `Authentication.getDetails()`, and decides to authenticate for ADMIN access or for USER access.
- Two [`DaoAuthenticationProviders`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/package-summary.html), each with a [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html), one defining the queries for the ADMIN tables and the other one defining the queries for the USER tables.

As you can see, this requires some work. I strongly suggest to use a unified table structure for users, and a unified login page, if possible. That will give you a very standard Spring Security configuration. Then, you can customize that configuration a bit to redirect dynamically based on user role in case of login success.

Comment: Okay even if I use a single table but what I need to redirect to /admin/embassy when the person is having Admin Role and /user/embassy when the person is having User Role.

Is it possible with only one table structure ?

Comment: Please check the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930980/spring-security-conditional-default-target-url/11934678#11934678) at the end of my post there is a solution