# How to change login form to logout link once user is logged in?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a index.jsp page with a message and a login form which perfectly works, however when user is logged in I need it to stay on index.jsp page and just replace the login form with the logout link how to do this?

I know that I can use the following but do not know how to replace it with login form at runtime.

```
<a href="<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

**Login form which is in index.jsp**

```
<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method='post'> 
                <label for="j_username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"/><br/> 
                <label for="j_password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/><br/> 
                <input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'/> Remember me<br/>   
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Do you have a live website or JSFiddle that we can look at? The code you added doesn't really help lead to a solution.

Comment: No it works on my localhost what do you need to know I can upload the code, the index.jsp page just has a message and the above form, I just need to replace the form with logout link when user is logged in thats all.

Comment: Guess I'm not familiar with spring security. Found a similar post on SO though. May help you out a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139718/spring-security-changing-spring-security-login-form?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spring Security [taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6875) in conjuction with [SpEL expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-common-built-in):

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <a href="<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <!-- Login form goes here -->
</sec:authorize>
```